# Indeterminate and 2 as answer to $\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$ at x = 1

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

f(x) = $\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$

When we directly put x=1 to $\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$ without simplifying we get $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate form but on simplifying further $\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}  = \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}=x+1$ and then we put x=1, we get value as 2.

So is it right to say $\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$ is indeterminate and 2 as answer at x=1?

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: No. The expression is simply not defined at that point. We speak of indetermination with regards to limits but, even then, it is not a strict classification but rather a measure of our ignorance... it just means that we cannot guess the value of the limit by simple substitution.

Answer (score 1):

It would be right to say that it is an indeterminant form $(0/0)$ as $x=1$ is not in the domain of the function and the limiting value of the function is 2 as $x$ tends to 1 (not when equal) .

Answer (score 1):

There is an underlying issue.  Whether you can avoid regarding the fraction as indeterminate in the first place.  **Yes**, because the limit of a product is the product of limits.  So, the problem can be re-expressed as

$$\left[\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x-1}{x-1}\right] \times \left[\lim_{x\to 1} (x + 1) \right]. \tag{A} $$

Although L'Hopital's Rule can (if you wish) be applied to the first factor in (A) above, it is not really necessary.  That is, as $x$ approaches, but never equals $(1)$, it is clear that the first factor represents the constant value of $(1)$.

After a while, you get a feel of whether you can *shortcut* the process by simply cancelling terms.  Generally, yes, because (when two limits are each convergent), the product of the limits equals the limit of the product.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)$ is not defined at $x = 1$. However, there exist a continuous extension $g(x) = x+1$, defined in all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Isn't it wrong to say f(1) is not defined? Instead, it is indeterminate (0/0 form) at x=1.

Comment: No. $f(1)$ is not defined. The limit $lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$ is indeterminate with $\tfrac{0}{0}$ form. A function can not be indeterminate at a point, either it is defined (as a real value in this case) or it is not.